# Parsing binary output from sensor to float

Tags: parsing, binary, hex, sensors, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert the binary output from an IMU sensor ([VectorNav VN100](https://www.vectornav.com/docs/default-source/documentation/vn-100-documentation/vn-100-user-manual-(um001).pdf?sfvrsn=b49fe6b9_32)) to a float. The example given in the user manual is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEmGH.png).
In the example in the user manual (pg 41) the hexadecimal digit 0x422E5093 converts to a float value of +43.578686.... how???
When I convert I get a float value of 1110331539

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was a misunderstanding of the problem on my part.
An online [floating point to hex converter](https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/) outlines the procedure for converting. Hopefully this will be of use to someone else!